# How to shift cell/div contents after dynamically removing one cell/div?

Tags: php, html

I am making a demo restaurant menu order page. Each selected menu item is pushed into a session array (only the item ID is stored). I am then displaying the order for confirmation.

I am dynamically creating and populating divs with the menu item details by pulling rows from the database, where 1 row goes in 1 div (stacked on top of each other). After every 4 items, I start a new 'column' - a containing div that is floated next to the first 'column'/containing div, and the next 4 items are put in this containing div. After every 12 items, I start a new page (like starting a new table). So the arrangement on the page is 3 columns with 4 rows each.

I have given an option to remove a menu item from the order. I can remove the item from the array, but when the page reloads, there is an empty space where the item was, and the counting system I have for tracking every 4 or 12 rows is not reset, so adding new or removing items messes up the 4 row system I have set up.

Is there a way to 'shift' the items/repopulate the divs every time an item is removed, so that there are no empty spaces and there are always a max of 4 items per 'column'?

I can also use an actual table to display the items (instead of divs), if that makes 'shifting' the items easier.

I am new to PHP so there may be things I have coded that may not be the best way (I'm still learning!)

```
<section data-state="order">

<div class="pageContainer">

    <div class="menuColumn">
        <?php   
            // loop through session order array                                                 
            foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $key => $value) {

                // get info from db for items in array
                $query = "SELECT id, name, price, image FROM tblMenuItems WHERE id = '$value'";

                $result = @mysqli_query($connect_db,$query);        

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                    // store data in variables
                    $id = stripslashes($row[0]);
                    $name = stripslashes($row[1]);
                    $price = stripslashes($row[2]);
                    $image = stripslashes($row[3]);

                    $total += $price;

                    // after 4 items, start a new 'column'                              
                    if ($key % 4 == 0 && $key != 0) {
                        echo '
                        </div> <!-- end .menuColumn -->

                        <div class="menuColumn">
                        ';
                    }

                    // after 12 items, start a new section (page)
                    if ($key % 12 == 0 && $key != 0) {
                        echo '
                            </div> <!-- end .menuColumn -->
                            </div> <!-- end .pageContainer -->
                            </section> <!-- end section -->

                            <section data-state="order">
                            <div class="pageContainer">
                            <div class="menuColumn">';
                    }

                    // display ordered items and info on page
                    echo '
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <div class="menuItem">
                            <img class="imgMenuItem" src="images/'.$image.'" alt="Menu Item">
                            <h4>'.$name.'</h4> 
                            <h5>$'.$price.'</h5>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnRemoveItem" class="btnRemoveItem" value="Remove Item">    
                            <input type="hidden" name="remove" value="'.$id.'">           
                        </div> <!-- end .menuItem -->
                    </form>

                    <br class="clear">
                    ';
                } // end while

            } // end foreach 

        ?>

    </div> <!-- end .menuColumn -->

</div> <!-- end .pageContainer -->
```

To remove an item from the array, I have this at the top of my page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnRemoveItem'])) {       
    // remove menu item from array (including all multiples)
    foreach (array_keys($_SESSION['order'], $_POST['remove']) as $remove) {
        unset($_SESSION['order'][$remove]);         
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `unset()` you can set the key to `null` and when you iterate over the array you check if its null and render a blank div on the place.